# Declare variable syntax invalid in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I'm trying to run a simple code that had already run on another machine and worked perfectly, now that I try to run it on my machine I get the syntax error.

I run it in Workbench Version 8.0

```
delimiter $$
create function funcion_mul(P_NUM2 INT)
returns INT
begin
    DECLARE declare valor_final INT default 0;
    RETURN valor_final;
END;
$$
delimiter ;
```

"DECLARE" is no valid at this position for this server version, expecting :

¿Qué es lo que está mal?

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo: `DECLARE declare`

Answer (score 1):

What about removing the `declare` duplication ?

```sql
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION funcion_mul(P_NUM2 INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE valor_final INT default 0;
    RETURN valor_final;
END;
$$
delimiter;
```